# Magento 2 - Check in mini cart if product is virtual

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.4, mini-cart, knockout, virtual-products

How can we check in the mini cart if the product is virtual using knockout?

Inside the cart and checkout we can use the following, but that is not working in the mini cart. Any idea?

```
<!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
<!-- /ko -->
```